# Could a human metamorphosis work?

Tags: science-based, biology, xenobiology, anatomy, genetic-engineering

I was playing Resident Evil 6 and I was wondering if it could be possible with the help of a virus to make humans metamorphose.

The girl in the videogame basically turns into a chrysalis and by the end of it it's another person. I wanted to create more or less the same thing for my sci-fi book; would it be possible with the help of genetic engineering to create a virus that could turn a human into goo-like metamorphosis and regrow the person?

Comment: I've watched Resident Evil 6 (I guess that's what RE6 means), but I don't quite recall the scene, and others might not have the reference. Therefore can you explain in more details the process of metamorphosis you want? Time to transform, difference in size and shape, cell change (I believe RE6 changes to mushrooms, but what about yours?), etc. The more detailed, the more we can say aye or naye without resorting to "it's your world, you're free to tell if it's possible or not".

Comment: Related: [Can mammals go through metamorphosis?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/q/23298/55743).

Comment: This depends on the rules of your world. In a world with the magic write-your-way-out-of-anything T-Virus sure why not. We're a worldbuilding site, not a speculate about the real world site. Without providing us with the specific rules your world follows this questions is not a good fit.

Comment: VTC as a duplicate of https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/q/233442/40609 and https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/q/233596/40609, which can't be used to close as a duplicate because SE has changed how closing as duplicates can happen. If for no other reasons, this Q is opinion-based and violates the book rule. The answer is "yes, it's your world. Now ask us specific questions about how you intend to implement it. We're good at that."

Comment: @JBH Your second link is a closed question, which links to a dead link. Voting to close this question on that basis will lead to a question that has been asked multiple times but with zero answers. 

Can you show that this is actually a duplicate?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can a virus that causes forced evolution exist?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/195587/can-a-virus-that-causes-forced-evolution-exist)

Comment: Summary of the question marked as duplicate: No.

Comment: @stix Questions need neither be answered nor active to be sourced as a duplicate - and this Q is a duplicate of both those links. The fact that they've been closed and/or deleted underscores the unsuitability of the question, not the unsuitability of the duplicate assignment.

Answer (score 3):

## A very large virus could do it.

Growing humans is hard. A huge and complex and interconnected set of systems are grown from a single cell with complex signalling systems and interconnected protein chains used to say what grows where.

You can't rely on that. You want to grow a new person from scratch with all the person. Yeah, you can do it, but it's orders of magnitude more complex than making a human. You'll need a huge virus that's substantially bigger than human cells, or a mix of viruses.

The way insects like butterflies do it is they basically evolved to have one of their embryonic forms emerge early, and then successive rounds of evolution exagerated the features of each form. They have a common, well thought out plan for how they develop, with their bodies breaking down into different bags of organs which serve as the seeds to regrow into their new form, the end of embryonic development.

Humans are fully developed as adults so you can't do this, so you'll need a massively more complicated virus which basically breaks a human down into bags of organs and broken down proteins and fats and carbohydrates. It uses that existing structure as a seed to make a new form more appropriate to the person, massively boosting stem cell production and changing body parts around as appropriate.

If it's an actual virus and not a magical super nanobot thing, this will take a long time- weeks or months.